# Prove for vectors that $||x||_{1} \ge ||x||_{\infty}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I understand that it is true when I draw it out, but I can't seem to prove it formally. How do I go about proving this?

This is how I proved that $||x||_{1} \ge ||x||_{2}$

$||x||_{1}^2 = (\sum\limits_{i=1}^n |x_{i}|)^2 = |x_{1}|*|x_{1}
| + |x_{2}||x_{2}| + .... + |x_{n}||x_{n}| \ge x_{1}*x_{1}$.... etc (CBS inequality)

But I can't seem to get the one in the title to click for me.

Comment: Note that you second equality is bogus. Look up binomial theorem if you want to know how to expand the square of a sum. Not needed for this particular case, though. For finite-dimensional spaces built on normed spaces, $\|x\|_p \le \|x\|_q$ for all $p \ge q$ including $p=\infty$

Comment: Ah that was my bad. I wrote that out a little too quickly. For got to include the terms where $i \ne j$... Ah well, I'll leave it up there as a reminder to not rush it -.-

Answer (score 4):

The one-norm is the sum of absolute values of the entries, which includes in particular the largest such entry in absolute value.  This last is the $\infty$-norm.

Comment: Put another way: let $j\in\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ be any index satisfying $|x_j|=\max_i |x_i|=\|x\|_\infty$. Then $$\|x\|_1=\sum_i|x_i|=|x_j|+\sum_{i\neq j}|x_i|\geq |x_j|=\|x\|_\infty$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $x=(x_1, x_2, ..., x_n)\in\mathbb{R}^n$. For all $i=1,...,n$, we have
$$\left| {{x_i}} \right| \leqslant \left| {{x_1}} \right| + ... + \left| {{x_i}} \right| + ... + \left| {{x_n}} \right| \equiv \sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\left| {{x_k}} \right|}  = {\left\| x \right\|_1 }.$$
This leads to $\mathop {\max }\limits_{1 \leqslant i \leqslant n} \left| {{x_i}} \right| \leqslant {\left\| x \right\|_1},$ or ${\left\| x \right\|_\infty } \leqslant {\left\| x \right\|_1}$.